# Unable to import key vault certificate to app service - Failed to get App Service Service principal details

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

I have a SSL cert in my Azure key vault that I am trying to import to the correct App Service.

I am the owner of the Azure subscription and I have given the App Service GET and LIST permissions for certificates on the vault.

On my App Service I click TLS/SSL settings > Private Key Certificates (.pfx) > Import Key Vault Certificate

This is the message I receive

[image]

Another owner on the subscription is able to complete this process successfully. So I am not sure why I am not able to when we both have owner roles on the subscription?

Is anyone able to offer any suggestions please?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

***When you are trying the operation from `Azure Portal` and you are a `Owner` of the `Subscription`, then Azure by default adds a `access policy` for the `Azure APP Service` Resource Provider and you do not further require to add the any access policies for the Web App.***

**Example:**

***I created a Web App with system managed identity and a Key vault with the below added Access Policies. I am an Owner of the Subscription and a User in the Azure Active Directory.***

[image]

**When , I perform the import certificate operation in the `TLS/SSL Settings`, the access policy get automatically updated with the `Azure App Service` Service Principal Credential.**

[image]

[image]

***In your case its not able to find the details of the `Resource Provider` Service Principal. As a Solution you can try adding `Microsoft.Azure.CertificateRegistration (i.e. ObjectId : ed47c2a1-bd23-4341-b39c-f4fd69138dd3)` , `Microsoft Azure App Service (Internal) (i.e. ObjectId : 505e3754-d8a9-4f8b-97b6-c3e48ac7a543)` & `Microsoft Azure App Service (i.e. ObjectId : f8daea97-62e7-4026-becf-13c2ea98e8b4)` in access policy for key vault.***

[image]

**Note: If the Issue is still not resolved , Please reach out to Azure Support for better assistance.**